# ImageButton and runat = server property

Tags: c#, asp.net

im doing some test with the flicker API and i got a wierd problem afther i changed some controls in my code.

when i first tried to requst images i stored them in a Image and every thing work great but i want to do other stuff to the image so i tried using ImageButton class and i get an exception that it got to have run="server" property.

i adding all the controls programmticly.

what is wierd for me is that the class Image didnt gave any excpetion but using a class that inherit from him did.

so my qustion is: it possibly to add and check if the control have the runat="server" property via c# code?

(sorry for my english)

here is some of my code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string key = "*****************";
    string secret = "***********";
    MyFlicker myFlicker = new MyFlicker(key, secret);
    int photoCount = myFlicker.coll.Count;
    try
    {
        string[] urls = myFlicker.GetPhotosURLS();
        string[] desc = myFlicker.GetPhotosDescreptions();
        string[] Titels = myFlicker.GetPhotosTitle();

        Panel[] panels = new Panel[photoCount];
        ImageButton[] images = new ImageButton[photoCount];
        Label[] descreptions = new Label[photoCount];
        Label[] titles = new Label[photoCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < photoCount; i++)
        {
            panels[i] = new Panel();
            images[i] = new ImageButton();
            descreptions[i] = new Label();
            titles[i] = new Label();


            titles[i].Text = Titels[i] + ":כותרת התמונה";
            images[i].ImageUrl = urls[i];

            if (descreptions[i] != null)
                descreptions[i].Text ="תיאור התמונה: " + desc[i];
            else
                descreptions[i].Text = "descreption was not found!";

            panels[i].ID = "panel" + i;
            images[i].ID = "image" + i;
            descreptions[i].ID = "des" + i;
            titles[i].ID = "titles" + i;

            panels[i].Controls.Add((Label)titles[i]);
            panels[i].Controls.Add((Label)descreptions[i]);
            panels[i].Controls.Add((Image)images[i]);
            this.Controls.Add((Panel)panels[i]);




        }


    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }



}
```

here is the apsx:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Copy_of_galleryControlTest_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What line of code exactly generates the error you described?

Comment: Why don't you use a repeater or something?

Comment: @ShadowWizard it dosnt tell me for some reson and the code it self is in try and catch.

Comment: 99% that the error you get is not directly because of the code you posted. Please post your `.aspx` markup as well and we'll see. (notify after you add, I don't check regularly every post I visit)

Comment: @ShadowWizard i added the aspx code (thank you for trying to help me).

Comment: And the server side code you posted is located in the `Page_Load` method of `Default.aspx.cs` file?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeap, should i add all the code?

Comment: What is Copy_of_galleryControlTest_Default ?

Comment: samy - yes, post the whole Page_Load code please..

Comment: @AdrianIftode i made the aspx page in diffrent folder and then i moved it to another folder becuse i didnt want to be cofused becuse its only a test. (didnt even notice that long name lol)

Comment: are you sure the class name is the same as the inherits value?

Comment: I could replicate it myself too :P

Comment: Sorry can't see any problem with the code itself. Can you post screenshot of the error page you see?

Comment: @AdrianIftode im not sure i understand the qustion, what class do u mean? and i should add that every thig worked befor i change the controls to ImageButton controls. so im pretty sure that problem is not from there, and i dont mind making another project to test this if that what  you advise me to do.

Comment: don't do it, I could replicate it myself, dynamically adding an ImageButton seems to give this error (even the form is runat server)

Comment: i noticed that in the line `panels[i].Controls.Add((Image)images[i]);` you are casting to `Image` and not to `ImageButton`. maybe this is the problem?

Comment: @Menahem nope i tried that its still give the same error

Comment: here is the link for the error image http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/263/errorepage.png/

Comment: thank you all for all the help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a test similar to this code, I got this error

> Control 'ctl03' of type 'ImageButton' must be placed inside a form tag
>   with runat=server.

then I changed from

```
this.Controls.Add((Panel)panels[i]);
```

to

```
form1.Controls.Add((Panel)panels[i]);
```

And it makes sense now.. ImageButton is a submit control ( a control which would submit the form), so this why this error, the control needd to be a child of the form1 and not outside it

Another workaround is to override this method, but I recommend the first one

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    ;
}
```

Comment: i changed the coded with the solution you offerd me but  it still genreate the same exception and its wierd becuse the code is in try and catch and still dosent show what line of code throw it.